# Rewriting configuration file at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration-files

I'm using configuration files via configparser in python3.7.1.
I have a variable in one of the files that I would like to modify at runtime an was wondering what is the best way to do it.

Right now I rewrite the entire file as so:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
config['Categorie']['new_variable'] = variable
with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

I have 2 concerns with this method:

- potentially losing the config on an error
- deleting comments in the file each time

Comment: If you want to keep the comments, I'd suggest switching to YAML and using the [`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. As for safe update - write to a new file (i.e. `file.new`), delete the old one (i.e. `file.conf`), rename the new one into the default name (i.e. `file.conf`). When reading the config, attempt to read the default name (`file.conf`), if not available, try to read the new config (`file.new`) just in case the rename failed on the last update. Alternatively, use a database (`sqlite` should be fine) for your config and rely on the DB engine for atomicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configparser` doesn't store comments, so you're stuck on that one unless you *don't* use this module... Or you could extract the comments and reinject them in the file afterwards (losing the position of the comments, but keeping the contents)

To avoid losing the configuration in case of an error (disk full or other) you could save as another name, delete the current file and rename.

```
conf_file = 'config.ini'
with open(conf_file+'.bak', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
if os.path.exists(conf_file):
   os.remove(conf_file)  # else rename won't work when target exists
os.rename(conf_file+'.bak',conf_file)
```

this method is safe. If file cannot be written, the previous file isn't clobbered. Worst case is (if someone pulls the plug at the *exact* moment when the original file is removed) the `.bak` file (with proper new contents) remains.

An alternative would be to rename existing .ini file, write the new one, and delete the old .ini file when the file has been successfully written.

All operations are performed on the same drive, so there's no more disk access (except for the renaming), even if the file is huge.

Comment: This would indeed allow me to keep the comments but I think it would then be much harder to control the format of the file

Answer (score -1):

config.ini

```
[DEFAULT]
ServerAliveInterval = 45
Compression = yes
CompressionLevel = {somelevel}
ForwardX11 = yes
```

python code

```
content = open('config.ini').read()
somelevel = 34
filled = content.format(**locals())
gg = ConfigParser()
gg.read_string(filled)
```

However, do **NOT** use **locals() for real code.
Do try to look for a better way, this is dirty.

edit : I tried do do some simple f string hacks, they fail due to escaping issues.